# running 3rd party software using my own process

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, exe

I have a 3rd party software which i need to run using my own process written in c#, which is running as a windows process.

Windows doesnt allow my process (permission issues) to run a 3rd party exe file because of protection from malicious code.

I am using a service called "alywasup" to handle my process but it caused issues and i got into a world of pain with windows "session0"

is there an option to allow my process to run another exe file as administrator on windows server 2012?

### EDIT:

This it's actually a service not a process and on service there are limitation that doesnt exist on the process

Comment: Yes, `Process.Start`?

Comment: @aevitas i edited my question, it's probably due to the fact that it's a service not a process

Comment: Ah, now it's an entirely different beast!

Comment: yeap...sry for that :)

Comment: If its a service have you tried simply starting it? (via ServiceController)

Comment: @AlexK. yeap....tried it, according to c# experts - Windows services run is an isolated session and not within user context so they are not allowed to have any interaction with the user

Comment: That does not mean you cannot start and stop them.  What is the problem? does it not start? what's the exact error?